# Place Order not working in Magento 1.9

Tags: onepage-checkout

I upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9. At checkout, when client clicks on 'Place Order', it just shows a circling motion (submitting order information) and it reloads the page. I saw somewhere that that solution is: Magento 1.9.1.0 requires that your server has php-mbscript (mbstring) enabled in Apache.

I had a chat with Hostgator and they said they cannot enable this for me as I am on a shared hosting account. Does that mean my clients can no longer checkout in my store? What can I do please? Thank you

Comment: Once check `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml` file has form key. check bottom of this file and compare it with `base` package file

Comment: Hello Rohit, can you kindly explain better. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Magento requires the mbstring library to work. I suggest you upgrade your hosting account or look for another hosting company. As you said, checkout won't work anymore without this library installed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the problem of "Place Order not working" compare base info file with that of your theme and as said check the `getFormKey` function.

Please add following code (you can comment out your current code using php tag `/*`  content  `*/`)

```
//<![CDATA[
    review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in which file we add

```
//<![CDATA[
    review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
//]]>
</script>
```